# Insert elements of a Queue in a Stack java

Tags: java, stack, queue

I'm making an exercise, this is the text:
The function takes as input a queue Q, an empty stack S and an integer k and inserts the first k elements of Q in S so that the element at the front of Q is at the top of S and the k-th element of Q is at the bottom of S.For example, if Q = <6,8,7,15,20,9>, where 6 is the element at the front, then after calling insert (Q, S, 4) we have S = <6,8,7,15>, where 6 is the element at the top.
I can't use any data structure.
This is my solution but not work properly, I insert the elements in wrong order...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Queue<String>Q=new ArrayQueue<String>();
    Stack<String>S=new ArrayStack<String>();
    Q.enqueue("Bob");
    Q.enqueue("Tom");
    Q.enqueue("Ann");
    Q.enqueue("Bill");
    Q.enqueue("David");
    Q.enqueue("Mary");
    Q.enqueue("Bob");
    Q.enqueue("Jane");*/

    for(int k=1;k<=9;k++){
      insert(Q,S,k);
      System.out.print("Dopo aver invocato insert con k="+k +", S = < ");
      while(!S.isEmpty())
         System.out.print(S.pop()+" ");
      System.out.println(">");
    }
}

public static <E>void  insert(Queue<E> Q,Stack<E> S, int k){
        int sizeOfQ=Q.size();
        if(sizeOfQ<k)
            return;
        for(int i=0;i<k;i++){
            E elt=Q.dequeue();
            Q.enqueue(elt);
        }
        for(int i=0;i<sizeOfQ;i++){
            E elt=Q.dequeue();
            if(i>=sizeOfQ-k){
                S.push(elt);
                Q.enqueue(elt);
            }else{
                Q.enqueue(elt);
            }
        }
        for(int i=0;i<sizeOfQ-k;i++){
            Q.enqueue(Q.dequeue());
        }
```

Comment: Could you explicitate the package for Queue? It couldn't be java.util.Queue since there is no dequeue method.

Comment: yes is not from java util...http://pastebin.com/6dQpXd0p this is ArrayQueue

Comment: The imports are important as much as the code... your ArrayQueue doesn't compile...and may I have ArrayStack also?

Answer (score 0):

Obviously this is a sort of exam, so I can't give you a direct answer.

What I can do is to show you a direction to find the solution.

---

Try to write the problem in a different form:

- If k is 0 return an empty stack
- If k is 1 return a stack with the first element of the queue
- If k is 2 and the element in front of the queue are A and B returns a stack with B at the bottom and A at the top, so you need to insert first B and for second A
- If k is 45 and the element in front of the queue is A you need to insert A and then insert in reverse order the other 44 elements

Written in this form it seams a recursion algorithm. Isn't it?

If you can use recursion this problem is very simple.

Take only in attention two points:

- What happens to your queue Q? It is possible to change it? Or at the end of the process you need to have the original Q?
- What happens if k is greater than the size of Q? Returns an Exception? returns a stack for all the elements of Q

---

If a recursion is not possible you need to insert a new data structure (list? array? another stack, any possibilities works well in this case) to maintain the intermediate steps.

Comment: my Queue must be the original Q at the end of the process, if k is greater i haven't instructions..

Comment: Are you free to use additional data structures?